# Imaging base of HDR range

Tags: photonics

When speaking about HDR photography, do the magnitudes are measured in base 2 (stops) or base 10 (decibel)?

I mean - what is the magnitude in linear scale of, for example, 100 dB HDR?

Comment: So you are asking if 100 dB is measured in decibels? I don't understand your example. Can you give a different example?

Comment: I mean - 100 dB in regular decibels is magnitude of 10000000000. It seems physically too much, if I think in terms of luminance that is reated to shutter speed. Maybe the base of the log scale is not 10, but 2 for example? it makes much more sense.

Comment: Actually stops would make less sense.  2^100 is waaaay bigger than 10^10.  "Normal" JPEG files are 8 stops, RAW files are 10 - 12 stops, and most HDR is 14-16 stops.  100 stops is unheard of.  Also dB is always a power ratio, so if the context was voltage (for example a voltage amplifier), then 100 dB is only a factor of 100,000 (because power goes with voltage squared), which is reasonable for HDR.  Can you give an example of the context in which you've seen "100" referring to HDR?

Comment: Many HDR image sensors promise dymanic range of more then 100 dB. Here is one example: https://www.imagesensors.org/Past%20Workshops/2019%20Workshop/2019%20Papers/R31.pdf here it is 120 dB which is more then 17 stops (2^17), this is why I am not fully understand how I treat dymanic range in dB in term of luminance magnitudes.

Answer (score 1):

I could be misinterpreting the article, but to my understanding, I believe the key number to look at is the "full well capacity" of the sensor. They are quoting this as 785,000 electrons.  So the minimum the sensor could put out is 1 electron, and the most it could put out is 785,000 electrons.  Log base 10 of 785000 = 5.9, and 5.8 * 20 = 118.  That's not quite 120 which they quote, but it's close.  So maybe they rounded up somewhere.  One point is that you multiply by 20, not 10, because power would not go with the number of electrons, but rather the square, and decibels is always a power ratio.  A ratio of 785,000:1 would be a little more than 19 stop.  So I think you are interpreting this correctly.

Keep in mind that this is a research paper, so they are just showing off that they build a super good sensor.  It may or may not be cost effective to build this and put it into a production camera, at least not yet.